# RawInput resolution

Tags: c++, raw-input

I'm working with Win32 RawInput API to monitor mouse events for a high def mouse. It's unclear from the documentation I've been able to find what scale is used to report mouse movements. More specifically, in the RAWMOUSE struct,  lLastX and lLastY report the relative motion of the mouse but what scale are we talking about? pixels? raw dots registered by the mouse?
Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: RawInput would report the *raw* data from a device. Mouse devices don't store/use absolute pixel coordinates as in screen coordinates. Instead they use delta in *mickey* unit. Wikipedia should have more details about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the number of steps. How many steps mouse reported in 1 inch depends on mouse sensitivity expressed in terms of count per inch (CPI).  See this [link](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_mouse_DPI).